# Многомерныый массив и его парсинг

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив вида:

```
[
    [ключ1] =>
               [0] => значение 1
               [1] => значение 2
    [ключ2] => 
               [0] => значение 1
               [1] => значение 2
    [ключN] =>
               [0] => значение 1
               [1] => значение 2
]
```

Как из него получить несколько массивов вида:

```
[ключ1] => значение 1, [ключ2] => значение 1, [ключN] => значение 1]
[ключ1] => значение 2, [ключ2] => значение 2, [ключN] => значение 2]
```

Я написал следующее решение, но я уверен существует более изящное. Хочу услышать критику и, возможно, лучшие практики:

```
$array // исходный массив    
$pos = array_slice($array, 1, 1); //запоминаем количество значений
                $pos = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $pos);
                $k = 0;
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($pos); $i++) 
                        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                            $arr[$key] = array_shift(array_slice($value, $i));
                            $k++;
                            if ($k == 8) { //количество значений
                              echo $arr // искомый массив
                              $k = 0
                            }       
                    }
```

Comment: Может вы о разделении массива на необходимое количество?  array_chunk()  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: В моем примере одной array_chunk не обойтись, если я вижу все варианты использования этой функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach((array)$array as $k1=>$v1){
    foreach((array)$v1 as $k2=>$v2){
        $out[$k2][$k1]=$v2;
    }
}

print_r($out);
```

Comment: Офигеееть! Как же всё, оказывается, просто. А я, блин, убил не один час на это. Спасибо //как же мне стыдно

Comment: @МасляковДмитрий, порой горе от ума - сам бывает на пустом месте ворочу такое! :)

Comment: Какой смысл от `(array)` в данном случае?

Comment: @Let'ssayPie, старая привычка - если включен вывод ошибок и напарываешься на "пустой массив"(ветку) ошибка не выскакивает.